# How to filter out rows in pandas without creating a mask?

Tags: python, r, pandas, tidyverse

Is there not a pretty pipe-way to do filtering in Python's Pandas like in R's tidyverse?

Most examples in Python vs R

```
# Pandas
Iris[(Iris.Petal_Width > 1) & (Iris.Species==’setosa’)][[‘Sepal_length’,’Petal_Length’]]

# Tidyverse
Iris %>% 
   filter(Petal_Width > 1, Species==’setosa’) %>%
   select(Sepal_Length, Petal_Length)
```

It is a very ugly syntax in Pandas, and there must be a better way. Python is pretty well known for its piping, when why not here?

Comment: `df.query('(Petal_Width > 1) & (Species=="setosa")')`

Comment: Thanks, I remembered there being a solution, but haven't been using pandas for ages :)

Comment: Have a look at "Effective Pandas" which brings pandas even more into tidyverse syntax.